Can I control a single light bulb with 2 single-pole switches on the same phase?
I'm building a cabinet with a light in it, and I have 2 micro switches that will allow the light to turn on when a door is opened. (It's a standard micro switch with a normally-open side and a normally-closed side.) But I want the light to turn on when either switch is on in case only one door is opened. The problem is that would create a "loop" for the hot wire. If both switches are on then the hot wire will split to go to each switch, but then come back together to power the bulb. (See diagram.) Is there anything wrong with that setup?
I'm in the US and this is a standard 120V AC bulb. The two hot wires are coming from the same outlet so they'll necessarily be on the same phase.


"The problem is that would create a "loop" for the hot wire" - why do you believe that this would be a problem?

I think you might want to look into three way switches.  Two switches control one light.  Each switch can turn on/off the light.  Used mainly for room with two doors/entrances, so you do not need to cross the room(step on legos) to turn on/off a light.  Go in one door and turn on the light, go out the other door and turn off the light.

@crip659 this is for 2 doors on the same cabinet.

@brhans, physically it doesn't seem to be a problem as it WORKS, I just wasn't sure if there were any hidden downsides I wasn't aware of. I'm moreso looking for those unknown unknowns.

It's possible to do this without 3-wire cable and without creating any inductive or radiating loops. Answer a few questions and I'll get you a diagram.

Is the cabinet built-in or standalone furniture? If standalone, how do you intend to supply electrical power? With a plug and lamp cord?

Where in your wiring will power be brought to the circuit? At the lamp or at one of the switches?

Is it more convenient to run a cable between the switches and from one switch to the lamp, or from the lamp to each switch separately?

You can absolutely do this.
You just have to be careful about the path the wires take.
All the current must flow on the same  cable or conduit
so it goes something like this:
The cable  between the two switches must have 3 power conductors so unless they are both in the same junction box you'll need /3 cable for this stretch.


To make sure I'm understanding correctly: have one wire go from the first switch to the second switch and one wire go from the first switch AROUND the second switch. Is that correct? So when the first switch is ON it delivers power to the bulb and when it's OFF it delivers power to the second switch, which in turn can turn the bulb ON or OFF.

Yes exactly like that.


If you use a relay with low voltage switching you can do this with no concerns.  You can wire the low voltage switches any way you want safely.   (See note below).
Legally: If the cabinet is built-in it would be governed by building regs and you just can't do this. You should just run two switch loops from the bulb. If it's free standing, so long as you don't sell it, you can legally build whatever you want in a box.  You need to worry about its safety but there are no regulations guiding you.
Safety: If it's just one light bulb, probably an LED one, the current involved here isn't going to cause a problem.  Anyway if your doors are all in a straight line, like any typical cabinet, it would be easy to do this without creating a loop.  Just run the neutral along the front of the cabinet past both doors.  .... but now you're putting junction boxes in the cabinet.  We go back to "why not low voltage"?

Note: If you use LED lighting it's tempting to put the switches on the low voltage side of the power supply, thus avoiding all questions of safety and regulation here.  But I recommend against that.  It's very easy to find relays that will use low voltage to switch 120V.  OTOH if you're switching on the low voltage side, the current is relatively high and the switches are hard to find and expensive.

Can I ask how low-voltage would help here? Wouldn't I still have the same "loop" problem as long as I only have 1 light? Also, I don't mind the junction boxes but I'm not sure how that would help. Are you saying that this would be OK if there were 2 completely separate circuits, even if they're both going to the same light? Thanks!

The problem with loops is that with bad design and enough power they can heat things up and start fires.   If you have a power supply designed for cabinet lighting you'd have to be VERY purposeful to start a fire that way, IE by creating a multiturn coil.  One big loop around a cabinet with a 50W power supply in a controlled setting (your cabinet) won't do it.

"Two separate circuits" .... go do some reading to differentiate a "switch loop" from the kind of loop you are trying to avoid.  So long as the live and neutral wire carrying current are inside the same cable, that doesn't constitute a heating loop.  So  you can have a cable (with a pair of wires) going from the light to one door, and another such cable to the other door.  These are called "switch loops" but since the current goes "there and back" inside one cable, it's not a loop in the sense of going around anything.

I wasn't aware of the term "switch loop" before but now I understand, thank you. To confirm, I'd be fine wiring up 2 switch loops to the same light? Even if both switches are on at the same time? Thanks again!

@GJK yeah, it's nonstandard but it'd work and be legal

It's not typical in home wiring because if you have two switches you don't usually want one of them to override the others.  But it is very typical to wire cabinets and closets this way.  Manufacturers of cabinets with 120V lighting didn't have to worry about loops and such because they are not subject to building regulations, but UL or similar product regulations where you can demonstrate (not easily) that your product is safe and wire it how you like.   Nowadays with LED lighting no manufacturer would run 120V through all the door switches.  But you can.

FWIW here is how I solved a similar problem with double bifold doors, using a relay to control the lighting and magnetic switches for the doors.  Because the switches were low voltage and not carrying any meaningful current, I could use cheap ones and not worry about electrical safety issues when wiring and installing them, which made it easier to conceal them.
